# What to do when Component needs to wait for data from Service?

Tags: angular

My angular component gets data from an injected service... the service looks like this:

```js
   //method inside Customer-Service
   getCustomers(): Observable <ICustomer> {
        return this.http.get('http://foo.com/_api/app/Customers')
        .map( (response: Response) => { return <ICustomer[]> response.json(); })
        .catch(this.handleError)
    }
```

In my component I create a subscription like so...

```js
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

    allCustomers: ICustomer[]
  
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,  private _custSvc: CustomerService ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._custSvc.getCustomers().subscribe(customers => { this.allCustomers = customers }, 
        (err) => console.log('something went wrong'),
        () => { console.log('yep... its done.') })
        
         //other methods below need allCustomers to be populated.
         doSomething()
         doSomethingElse()
      }
```

I want the doSomething and doSomethingElse methods to wait until allCustomers has data.   How do people approach this in Angular??

Comment: They call the methods that require that data from inside the callback where they actually have it.

Comment: thanks but i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Well, you see where you have `this.allCustomers = customers`? At that point, you know you have that data. Why not call the functions that need it *from there?* Please read up on async generally and observables specifically before continuing.

Answer (score 2):

As @[jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) mentioned, you need to make the doSomething() and doSomethingElse() function be called within the `next` event of the subscription. Code shown below.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this._custSvc.getCustomers()
      .subscribe((customers) => {
         this.allCustomers = customers;
         // Call the functions here:
         doSomething();
         doSomethingElse();
      }, 
      (err) => console.log('something went wrong'),
      () => { console.log('yep... its done.') })
   };
}
```

There are other ways to make the function calls execute when the customers data is populated, but this is the most obvious and logical way and will be what you need most of the time.